# How to associate a horizontal scrollbar to multiple groupbox.?

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I wanted to have a total of 8 groupbox in the Dialog box. I don't know how to associate the horizontal scrollbar so that I can scroll it down and access all the group box. In the code below I have added only 2 as an example. Any help is appreciated.

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 20, 81, 71))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
        self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea(Dialog)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 251, 251))
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtGui.QWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 249, 249))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.groupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 211, 81))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 171, 51))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.groupBox_2 = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.groupBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 211, 111))
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.groupBox_2)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 171, 84))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.verticalScrollBar = QtGui.QScrollBar(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalScrollBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 0, 16, 241))
        self.verticalScrollBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.verticalScrollBar.setObjectName("verticalScrollBar")
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL("accepted()"), Dialog.accept)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL("rejected()"), Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "GroupBox", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "GroupBox", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: Here is the picture]

Comment: Normally, `QScrollArea` would show scroll bars automatically when things become larger than the visible size. You wouldn't need to create a `QScrollBar` manually. Why are you creating one yourself?

Comment: Oh and, you are placing things manually with fixed sizes. Why aren't you using layout managers?

Comment: @Avaris: Nice on both points. That should almost be answer right there. Use the scrollbars that come with ScrollArea, and use layouts :-)

Comment: @Avaris I already tried adding more groupboxes under scrollarea and it did not automatically expand, as you mentioned. Can you provide any code if possible?.

Comment: @Jack: I'd guess the fixed sized `scrollWidgetContents` is the problem. I'll write up an answer.

Comment: @Avaris: You are absolutely right. I just removed the size part from my code and it appears to be working fine. Thanks for your help man.

Comment: @Jack: You're welcome. I don't know how you modified your code, but use layout managers. They'll make your life so much easier :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the comments, `QScrollArea` doesn't need manual `QScrollBar`. It will create when needed. I can't be sure what your problem is without seeing the 'not working' code, but my guess is the fixed sized items and their placement. You are probably putting things outside of the widgets margin or overlapping each other so that the inner widget does not grow appropriately.

Anyway, here is a minimal example that replicates your dialog (notice the scrollbar):

```py
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        scrolllayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        scrollwidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        scrollwidget.setLayout(scrolllayout)

        scroll = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)  # Set to make the inner widget resize with scroll area
        scroll.setWidget(scrollwidget)

        self.groupboxes = []  # Keep a reference to groupboxes for later use
        for i in range(8):    # 8 groupboxes with textedit in them
            groupbox = QtGui.QGroupBox('%d' % i)
            grouplayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
            grouptext = QtGui.QTextEdit()
            grouplayout.addWidget(grouptext)
            groupbox.setLayout(grouplayout)
            scrolllayout.addWidget(groupbox)
            self.groupboxes.append(groupbox)

        self.buttonbox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox()
        self.buttonbox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.buttonbox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)

        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(scroll)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonbox)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = MyDialog()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Avaris. I faced the same problem. This solution helped a lot.