# Issue with scrollarea in pyqt?

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt

This is the file I generated using qt-designer.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(1024, 600)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(Dialog.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        Dialog.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.graphicsView = QtGui.QGraphicsView(Dialog)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.graphicsView.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.graphicsView.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.graphicsView.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.graphicsView.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("graphicsView"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsView)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 4)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Add", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_4"))
        self.pushButton_2 = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Delete", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_2"))
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_4, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_5"))
        self.pushButton_3 = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_3.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Edit", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_3"))
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_5, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_3"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Connected", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.tableWidget = QtGui.QTableWidget(Dialog)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tableWidget"))
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 2, 0, 1, 3)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout_2"))
        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(Dialog)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tabWidget"))
        self.tab = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab"))
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.tab)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_6"))
        self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea(self.tab)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("scrollArea"))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtGui.QWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 701, 292))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("scrollAreaWidgetContents"))
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_7"))
        self.dockWidget = QtGui.QDockWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.dockWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dockWidget"))
        self.dockWidgetContents = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.dockWidgetContents.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dockWidgetContents"))
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.dockWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_8"))
        self.plainTextEdit = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit(self.dockWidgetContents)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Ignored, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.plainTextEdit.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.plainTextEdit.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("plainTextEdit"))
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit)
        self.dockWidget.setWidget(self.dockWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.dockWidget)


        self.dockWidget_2 = QtGui.QDockWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.dockWidget_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dockWidget_2"))
        self.dockWidgetContents_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.dockWidgetContents_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dockWidgetContents_2"))
        self.verticalLayout_9 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.dockWidgetContents_2)
        self.verticalLayout_9.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_9"))
        self.plainTextEdit_2 = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit(self.dockWidgetContents_2)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Ignored, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.plainTextEdit_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.plainTextEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("plainTextEdit_2"))
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit_2)
        self.dockWidget_2.setWidget(self.dockWidgetContents_2)
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.dockWidget_2)


    self.dockWidget_3 = QtGui.QDockWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.dockWidget_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dockWidget_3"))
        self.dockWidgetContents_3 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.dockWidgetContents_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dockWidgetContents_3"))
        self.verticalLayout_10 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.dockWidgetContents_3)
        self.verticalLayout_10.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_10"))
        self.plainTextEdit_3 = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit(self.dockWidgetContents_3)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Ignored, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Ignored)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.plainTextEdit_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.plainTextEdit_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("plainTextEdit_3"))
        self.verticalLayout_10.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit_3)
        self.dockWidget_3.setWidget(self.dockWidgetContents_3)
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.dockWidget_3)    

        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.tab_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tab_2"))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, _fromUtf8(""))
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2, 2, 3, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Tab 1", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Tab 2", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The output is in the screenshot: The problem is that the Tab1 is not showing any scrollbar even I set the layout under scrollArea. The region where I am expecting a scrollbar is shown by a red rectangle.
           [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember this similar question :-) [How to associate a horizontal scrollbar to multiple groupbox.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624281/how-to-associate-a-horizontal-scrollbar-to-multiple-groupbox)

The reason you are still not getting proper scrollbars is because your widgets inside the scrollarea don't have a minimum height and are being allowed to shrink far enough down that they would never force the scrollarea to display its scrollbars.

In code, you can fix this by:

```
self.dockWidgetContents.setMinimumHeight(100)
```

Althought, you shouldn't be making any direct edits to this file being generated from Qt Designer. What you should do is go into QtDesigner, select the widgets, and at the top of their property list, set a minimum height for them.

Comment: man that worked perfectly fine. But here is another problem. For some reason I have to change the contents of my dialog. Instead of dockWidget I used a groupBox and in that case setting the minimum height did not work. Can you explain it why or do you want me to post the whole code. Thanks for your help

Comment: A small portion of the code can be found here [link](http://pastebin.com/KUVWxDCg)

Comment: There isn't enough context in this snippet for me to know exactly, but, a QGroupBox is a subclass of a QWidget all the same as a dockWidget or whatever else. The fixed height is a QWidget property. So it should all function the same. If its not, then you have issues with the child widgets and the layouts in which they are in

Comment: the complete code is posted [here] (http://pastebin.com/FJ6wPQuB). I appreciate your help man. Thanks for your time.

Comment: 1) Your original UI file would be a lot easier since this converted file contains a lot of extra designer junk. 2) Stop setting everything to ignored size policies. You are having layout issues because you aren't letting the layouts do their job. Just let those things be preferred. Your group boxes seem to hit their minimum size just fine and the scroll bars appear. The little overlapping artifacts are probably from your mixed size and layout settings for the various widgets.

Comment: I got it. I basically removed some properties and added dockwidget instead of  group and it worked. Thanks man

Comment: Thanks! This helps so much! Calling `setFixedWidth` surprisingly doesn't make the widgets have that width and allow widgets to overlap